# virtual machine not connecting to iso file

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

Several times I have fired up VMWare Workstation player to run Ubuntu and the error I am getting is this:

> Error while powering on:  VMWare Player cannot connect to the virtual machine. Make sure you have the rights to run the program, access all directories the program uses and access all directories for temporary files.
>
> Failed to connect pipe to virtual machine.  The system cannot find the file specified.

I have never used Linux before, I have always used Windows, all the way back to the 3.11 days.

Comment: Are you running VMWare Player on Windows?